# Turn off GET Access to ServiceStack Custom Credentials Provider

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

I know I ran across a post at some point, but I can't seem to find anything. It seems that by default, ServiceStack allows access to /auth via GET or POST. GET is not something we want in production.

I need to turn off GET access to /auth. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the AuthenticateServices custom ValidateFn to add your own custom validation, e.g:

```
AuthenticateService.ValidateFn = (authService, verb, requestDto) => {
    if (verb == HttpMethods.Get) 
        throw new NotSupportedException("GET's not allowed");
};
```

Otherwise you can add your own [Restricting Services Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services) on services you don't own by using the fluent API for dynamically adding attributes, e.g:

```
typeof(Authenticate)
    .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute(RequestAttributes.HttpPost));
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the ticket. I particularly like the second line if I do say so myself.